# Any way to Redirect Website to avoid SQL injection if Someone input Quot sign

Tags: php

Hi everyone i am new to PHP, is there any PHP code to redirect website to avoid sql injection if someone put quot sign like this

www.site.com/page.php?id=22'

here is website 
http://www.dgqadefence.gov.in/inner.php?id=566'

when i try to put ' site redirecting to http://www.dgqadefence.gov.in/index.php

i need code , thanks

Comment: You need to use Mod Rewrite to write you URL but that is not enough. If you are using your parameter `id` for db operations then you will need to use MySQLi with prepared statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: You could easily use this code:
`if (strpos($_GET["id"], '\'') !== false) {
    //code is safe
} else { header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
die(); }`